# Is it possible to create a Q-Q plot when lacking a coordinate system?

Tags: rascal

I'm looking to create a [Q-Q plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) within Rascal using the Vis library. I have been told there is no positional system. Is this true? If true, how would I go about plotting this or any scatterplot? Does anyone have an example of this in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Jurgen Vinju I wrote this code, hope it helps someone: https://gist.github.com/rlmhermans/c9e82a6a623b65f0c6957ab3ff2742cf

Answer (score 1):

That's an excellent question. Certainly Rascal's Vis library is "point free" in the sense that its layout mechanism has no absolute coordinate system. However, there are certain Figure kinds which have a relative coordinate system wrt their own "origin". When you combine several of those using horizontal, vertical or overlay boxes (and align them properly), you can create the effect of bar charts, scatterplots and whatever you desire.

In particular the `overlay` Figure composition is interesting: http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/Vis/Figure/Figure.html#/Rascal/Libraries/Vis/Figure/Figures/overlay/overlay.html

```
Figure point(num x, num y){ return ellipse(shrink(0.05),fillColor("red"),align(x,y));}
coords = [<0.0,0.0>,<0.5,0.5>,<0.8,0.5>,<1.0,0.0>];
ovl = overlay([point(x,y) | <x,y> <- coords]);
render(ovl);
```

Produces this (both code and image taken from the documentation linked above):

[image]

- Each point is an ellipse which is aligned at the `(x, y)` position relative to the origin of the enclosing `overlay` box.
- The origin by default of this `overlay` seems to be the upper-left corner, when no other FProperty's are given to the overlay. It's possible other alignment options for the `overlay` Figure also change the position of its origin.

Comment: I would also look at the `hscreen` and `vscreen` figures which help in projecting from a point in the scatter plot to places on the axis or even outside for labels related to the points.

Comment: Your advice has gotten me so far that I am now able to plot the data. I have given each point a popup with some indepth information. I use the mouseOver function. When multiple points are overlayed, this gives me multiple popups and I cannot find a way to prevent this. The onMouseClick function has a boolean return value to do this, but mouseOver returns a figure. Do you know of a way?

Comment: Nice progress! No that's a question I don't have an answer too; maybe one of my colleagues knows..